# PySpark / Spark Window Function First/ Last Issue

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

From my understanding first/ last function in Spark will retrieve first / last row of each partition/ I am not able to understand why **LAST** function is giving incorrect results.

This is my code.

```py
AgeWindow = Window.partitionBy('Dept').orderBy('Age')
df1 = df1.withColumn('first(ID)', first('ID').over(AgeWindow))\
        .withColumn('last(ID)', last('ID').over(AgeWindow))           
df1.show()
```

```
+---+----------+---+--------+--------------------------+-------------------------+
|Age|      Dept| ID|    Name|first(ID)                 |last(ID)                |
+---+----------+---+--------+--------------------------+-------------------------+
| 38|  medicine|  4|   harry|                         4|                        4|
| 41|  medicine|  5|hermione|                         4|                        5|
| 55|  medicine|  7| gandalf|                         4|                        7|
| 15|technology|  6|  sirius|                         6|                        6|
| 49|technology|  9|     sam|                         6|                        9|
| 88|technology|  1|     sam|                         6|                        2|
| 88|technology|  2|     nik|                         6|                        2|
| 75|       mba|  8|   ginny|                         8|                       11|
| 75|       mba| 10|     sam|                         8|                       11|
| 75|       mba|  3|     ron|                         8|                       11|
| 75|       mba| 11|     ron|                         8|                       11|
+---+----------+---+--------+--------------------------+-------------------------+
```

Answer (score 33):

It is not incorrect. Your window definition is just not what you think it is.

If you provide `ORDER BY` clause then the default frame is `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`:

```
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
from pyspark.sql.functions import first, last

w = Window.partitionBy('Dept').orderBy('Age')

df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(38, "medicine", 4), (41, "medicine", 5), (55, "medicine", 7)],
    ("Age", "Dept", "ID")
)

df.select(
    "*",
    first('ID').over(w).alias("first_id"), 
    last('ID').over(w).alias("last_id")
).explain()
```

```
== Physical Plan ==
Window [first(ID#24L, false) windowspecdefinition(Dept#23, Age#22L ASC NULLS FIRST, specifiedwindowframe(RangeFrame, unboundedpreceding$(), currentrow$())) AS first_id#38L, last(ID#24L, false) windowspecdefinition(Dept#23, Age#22L ASC NULLS FIRST, specifiedwindowframe(RangeFrame, unboundedpreceding$(), currentrow$())) AS last_id#40L], [Dept#23], [Age#22L ASC NULLS FIRST]
+- *(1) Sort [Dept#23 ASC NULLS FIRST, Age#22L ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
   +- Exchange hashpartitioning(Dept#23, 200)
      +- Scan ExistingRDD[Age#22L,Dept#23,ID#24L]
```

This means that the window function never looks ahead and the last row in the frame is the current row.

You should redefine the window as

```
w_uf = (Window
   .partitionBy('Dept')
   .orderBy('Age')
   .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing))

result = df.select(
    "*", 
    first('ID').over(w_uf).alias("first_id"),
    last('ID').over(w_uf).alias("last_id")
)
```

```
== Physical Plan ==
Window [first(ID#24L, false) windowspecdefinition(Dept#23, Age#22L ASC NULLS FIRST, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, unboundedpreceding$(), unboundedfollowing$())) AS first_id#56L, last(ID#24L, false) windowspecdefinition(Dept#23, Age#22L ASC NULLS FIRST, specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, unboundedpreceding$(), unboundedfollowing$())) AS last_id#58L], [Dept#23], [Age#22L ASC NULLS FIRST]
+- *(1) Sort [Dept#23 ASC NULLS FIRST, Age#22L ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
   +- Exchange hashpartitioning(Dept#23, 200)
      +- Scan ExistingRDD[Age#22L,Dept#23,ID#24L]
```

```py
result.show()
```

```
+---+--------+---+--------+-------+
|Age|    Dept| ID|first_id|last_id|
+---+--------+---+--------+-------+
| 38|medicine|  4|       4|      7|
| 41|medicine|  5|       4|      7|
| 55|medicine|  7|       4|      7|
+---+--------+---+--------+-------+
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I was trying other functions like lag, lead, cume_dist but they gave error for same window.
 `Window Frame specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, unboundedpreceding$(), unboundedfollowing$()) must match the required frame specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, 1, 1);`

Comment: Some functions can be applied only with a very specific frame. For example `lead` and `lag` are strictly defined by their offset.

Comment: It is good to know a solved bug https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-24033 about window functions in pyspark. Because of the bug you should check your spark version beforehand.

Comment: can u please help answer this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64004622/pyspark-need-help-in-capturing-first-and-last-date-on-dataset-grouped-by-mul