# Lead / lag functions throwing error when used over a row limited window in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

My code snippet:

```
val scoreDateByAccount = Window
      .partitionBy($"partition_column")
      .orderBy($"ordering_column")
      .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)

dataFrame
  .withColumn("new_column", lead($"ordering_column", 1).over(scoreDateByAccount))
```

This gives me an error:

> Window Frame specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, unboundedpreceding$(), unboundedfollowing$()) must match the required frame specifiedwindowframe(RowFrame, 1, 1);

If I then remove the `rowsBetween` portion of my snippet, no error ensues. If I choose any other function other than `lead` / `lag`, everything seems to work perfectly. I need to specify the window range because I intend to use that very same window to generate other columns (omitted here - deemed irrelevant) as well, and, according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52273364/7269570), among others, if I do not specify the rows limit, it will default to `rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow`, which is not acceptable for me.

I've also found a [bug report](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-24033) on Spark's Jira, from some 3 years ago, claiming that the `lag` function was broken (although the `lead` function worked properly for the OP), and the error thrown was quite similar to mine, but it is marked as Resolved nonetheless.

I also cannot find documentation on what kind of windows the `lead` / `lag` can be applied over.

What am I missing here?

Comment: `lead`/`lag` functions should be used when there is a need to look *ahead/behind* in rows respectively. If you have to use the window spec `(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)` with `lead` you should actually be using a different function, because you are looking at the entire dataset which isn't its intended use case. see the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.lead)

Comment: Yes, but, as I said, I'm using other functions as well. When you say "not intended", you mean "it will break"? Because, otherwise, that is not on point for me. I just don't want to define 3 different windows.

Also, the linked documentation doesn't really say anything concerning what type of window can the function be applied over. I know the function behavior. I just don't know the constraints.